# Regex to match numbers only if alphabets are present

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

I require a regex to match the string in the following way:

- `#1234abc` : *Should get matched*
- `#abc123`   : *Should get matched*
- `#123abc123` : *Should get matched*
- `#123`       : *Should **not** get matched*
- `#123_` : *Should **not** get matched*
- `#123abc_` : *Should get matched*

This implies that it should only get matched if the string contains numbers or underscore along with alphabets. Only numbers/underscore should not get matched. Any other special characters should not get matched either.

This regex is basically to get hashtags from string. I have already tried the following but it didn't worked well for me.

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+$)/', $text, $matches);
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: Are the strings tested separately or are you extracting them from larger text?

Comment: *This regex is basically to get hashtags from string* - your sample texts are not hashtags. If you need to match hashtags in the format you specified, try [`(?<!\S)#(?![0-9_]+\b)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/I8PGX5/1) (or its equivalent here - `(?<!\S)#(?=\w*\p{L})\w+`). Or just `(?<!\S)#\w*\p{L}\w*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match hashtags in the format you specified in a larger string, use

```
(?<!\S)#\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9gxQ2/2)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\S)` - there must be a start of string or a whitespace before
- `#` - a hash symbol
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars (that is, letters, digits or underscore)
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter (you may use `\p{L}` instead)
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars.

Other alternatives (that may appear faster, but are a bit more complex):

```
(?<!\S)#(?![0-9_]+\b)\w+
(?<!\S)#(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])\w+
```

The point here is that the pattern basically matches 1+ word chars preceded with `#` that is either at the string start or after whitespace, but `(?![0-9_]+\b)` negative lookahead fails all matches where the part  after `#` is all digits/underscores, and the `(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])` positive lookahead requires that there should be at  least 1 ASCII letter after 0+ word chars.

Comment: Are there any ways to accept hashtags in other languages also?

Comment: Yes, use `/(?<!\S)#\w*\p{L}\w*/u`. Or `/(?<!\S)#(?![0-9_]+\b)\w+/u`

Comment: I am using the first one. And it isn't accepting the second char here #早上.

Comment: See [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/6rfenQ). The `\w` with `/u` modifier will match base Unicode letters. You may use `'/(?<!\S)#[\w\p{M}]*\p{L}\p{M}*+[\w\p{M}]*/u'` to also account for diacritics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex:

```
((.*?(\d+)[a-zA-Z]+.*)|(.*[a-zA-Z]+(\d+).*)).
```

Access it here: http://regexr.com/3ef6q

see it working:

[image]

Comment: I tried it this way,  
    preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)#((.*?(\d+)[a-zA-Z]+.*)|(.*[a-zA-Z]+(\d+).*))/', $text, $matches);
Even the simple text did not work. 
For eg: My hat is #blue.
The result I should get is blue.

Comment: yes you're right I did not see that you need to match the string even if you don't have numbers. In this case the positive look ahead suggested by @Wiktor Stribiżew will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w_]+$
```

- `[\w_]+` matches one or more of letters, digits, `_`
- The zero width positive lookahead pattern, `(?=.*[A-Za-z])`, makes sure the match contains at least one letter

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8frN8/6)